# Writing a Custom Class to HDFS in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying to get familiar with the semantics of Flink after having started with Spark. I would like to write a `DataSet[IndexNode]` to persistent storage in HDFS so that it can be read later by another process. Spark has a simple `ObjectFile` API that provides such a functionality, but I cannot find a similar option in Flink.

```
case class IndexNode(vec: Vector[IndexNode],
                     id: Int) extends Serializable {
  // Getters and setters etc. here
}
```

The build-in sinks tend to serialize the instance based on the `toString` method, which is not suitable here due to the nested structure of the class. I imagine the solution is to use a `FileOutputFormat` and provide a translation of the instances to a byte stream. However, I am not sure how to serialize the vector, which is of an arbitrary length and can be many levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `SerializedOutputFormat` and `SerializedInputFormat`.

Try following steps:

1. Make `IndexNode` extend `IOReadableWritable` interface from FLINK. Make unserialisable fields `@transient`. Implement `write(DataOutputView out)` and `read(DataInputView in)` method. The write method will write out all data from `IndexNode` and read method will read them back and build all internal data fields. For example, instead of serialising all data from `arr` field in `Result` class, I write out all value out and then read them back and rebuild the array in read method.

   ```
   class Result(var name: String, var count: Int) extends IOReadableWritable {

     @transient
     var arr = Array(count, count)

     def this() {
       this("", 1)
     }

     override def write(out: DataOutputView): Unit = {
       out.writeInt(count)
       out.writeUTF(name)
     }

     override def read(in: DataInputView): Unit = {
       count = in.readInt()

       name = in.readUTF()

       arr = Array(count, count)
     }

     override def toString: String = s"$name, $count, ${getArr}"

   }
   ```
2. Write out data with

   ```
   myDataSet.write(new SerializedOutputFormat[Result], "/tmp/test")
   ```

   and read it back with

   ```
   env.readFile(new SerializedInputFormat[Result], "/tmp/test")
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that does work for a simpler use case I had. However, I don't think the answer adresses how to handle the nested structure. Do I have to traverse through all the elements in the vector (and their vectors) and repeatedly write the elements?

Comment: If the Vector class provides some method to write to / read from string or bytes, then you do not have to traverse.